# How many days unofficially does a publisher wait after the minor/major revisions deadline for a journal? Can they take actions against authors?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I have very limited time the current period and I need more time in order to address all the changes I get as feedback for my submitted journal paper, from the reviewers. The problem is that I need a couple of days (about 5) after the deadline they gave me. My questions are the following:

1. Can I extend the dealine (officially or unofficially)?
2. If I am "late" (5-6 days after the official deadline), do I have consequences?

What does your experience in similar cases indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to let the editor know if you need more time for the revision. This can for example be achieved by replying to the e-mail you got in which the editor gives you the deadline. Just ask for an extension and you will usually get it without having to explain too much why you need it.

Comment: The exception would be for a special issue that has a promised publish date. But normally if a paper doesn't make one volume it will be pushed to a future one. So, not a problem, just ask. Don't ghost the editor.

Comment: In Special Issues (not hardcopies), what is happening? Are they strict?

Comment: Special issues likely have firm publish dates and so firm finalization from the authors. They need to be strict to meet deadlines. The same is true, roughly, for conference submissions so that proceedings can be printed, though a few days might be acceptable. For ordinary submission to journals (print or not) it is less of an issue.